# Django model inheritance reverse_name issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, models, reverse

Let's start from the botton, this is what I want to achieve

```
class ClassA(model.Models):
    pass

class Class1(model.Models):
    fieldX = models.CharField()

class Class2(Class1):
    fieldY = models.BooleanField()

# all models are connected, and I prefere to have this situation
# I want to call related ClassA from both Class1 and Class2 using the 
# same property
c1 = Class1()
c1.class_a 

c2 = Class2()
c2.class_a 

# and, at the same time, call both Class1 and Class2 from ClassA
a = ClassA()
a.class_1
a.class_2
```

To solve this I am duplicating code (and I don't like it):

```
class Class1(model.Models):
    fieldX = models.CharField()

class Class2(model.Models):
    fieldY = models.BooleanField()
    fieldX = models.CharField()

class ClassA(models.Models):
    class_1 = models.OneToOneField(Class1, reverse_name='class_a')
    class_2 = models.OneToOneField(Class2, reverse_name='class_a')
```

The fields are much more than this dummy examples and modify them is quite annoying. How can I do that? I have lots of throubles with "reverse_name" field errors to achieve this, is there a workaroud?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you make three models that are connected, and not just a *single* model.

Comment: yes, they have specific methods too that manage datas and event triggers

Comment: Have you looked at the `foreignekey` fields?

Comment: Carl, that is the point, I have issues using foreignkey fields with reverse_name